# How to make objects accessible from anywhere within it's class

Tags: python, init

As a general strategy, is there a way to add objects to **init**, without initialization, while the code is being executed. For example, instead of:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = False
        self.b = False

    def set_values(self, in_boolean):
        if in_boolean:
            self.a = True
        else:
            self.b = True
```

Do this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = False

    def set_values(self, in_boolean):
        if in_boolean:
            self.a = True
        else:
            self.b = True
            # This object is only created if this condition is
            # met. Otherwise, this is not created in __init__.
```

Does one need to initialize any and all objects in `__init__` if they want to save an object there?

If this is not possible, what is an alternative method for creating global objects that are created within a class method?

I'll explain a scenario when I would want to use this so as to better illustrate the question:

Say I am executing a method within a class. Depending on certain conditions, an object may or may not be generated within that class that I would like to be able to access from all other methods within the class. Because the object may or may not be created, I don't wish to initialize it in `__init__`.

To sum it up: If I want to 'save' an object on my class, do I need to initialize it in `__init__`?

EDIT

Ok so my problem was that I believed one only created "self." objects in **init**. As I understand it now, one can make a "self." object anywhere in the class, not just in **init**. This would make said object accessible from anywhere else in the class, which is ultimately what I am looking for here. Maybe the question should have been:

How to I make objects accessible from anywhere in it's class?

Comment: In this case, the first approach works, right? You could just set `b` to `None` instead of `False`.

Comment: You won't get an error on the second code block. Did you tried that?

Comment: _"Obviously here I would get an error saying it doenst recognize self.b.
"_, no, you don't get any error.

Comment: Have you _tried_ what you posted?  You can add / reassign instance attributes in _any_ method, not just `__init__`.

Comment: `Obviously here I would get an error saying it doenst recognize self.b` <- have you tried this? It actually wouldn't give you an error at all

Comment: I now feel like I'm just an another brick in the wall...

Comment: Ok everyone is right I do not get an error.I thought if I don't define self.b in __init__ it wouldn't know what I was talking about.

Comment: `__init__` is **just another method**, albeit one that is automatically called whenever you create a new instance. Assigning to attributes on `self` is not magically creating those attributes.

Comment: @vikramls it would work but I guess the goal is to avoid initializing objects that may never need to be made.

Comment: @Malonge I added a closing comment to your question, but having read your comments, I might have been wrong in my interpretation.

Comment: @TankorSmash No I actually thing that does sum up my question very well.

Comment: I believe question should be reopened. OP has fixed it for the most part. The title of the question is still a little misleading, but the question pretty much sums up to "how do i self.?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, you don't need to 'declare' a variable before you use it at all. If you try to access a variable that doesn't exist, you can just wrap it in a `try...except AttributeError` and call it a day.

The `__init__` on a class is just like any other method on Python, it doesn't have access to any sort of functionality that the others don't. The only difference is that it has the benefit of being automatically called whenever you instantiate your class, saving you the trouble of having to write a constructor-like class every time and call it manually.

Comment: So one can make an object called self.object in any method in the class? Is that object then made global? Or should one just stick to using the global() statement?

Comment: no, it is NOT global. it is an object that belongs to the class. any other method inside the class that wants to can use that object by using `self.object`

Comment: Ok so what is the proper term used to describe objects that can be accessed anywhere within the same class?

Comment: @Malonge An attribute: A class attribute for the class object, and a data attribute for each individual instance of the class.